# Convert Line to central point in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, point, line, convert

I want to use QGIS to convert millions of lines (It's a Streetlayer.shp) to Points.
I know, that there is a way to do that but what I haven't figured out yet is following problem:

The conversion-tool uses a Reference-node left (unique id) and reference-node right (unique id) from the line and puts a point in center of these. As long as the line is straight it does what it's meant to do. When the lines has more than 2 nodes and **makes a curve** the conversion-tool still puts the point in the center of **reference-node left** and **reference-node right** which isn't on the line anymore (see picture attached).

[image]

Is there a way to make sure that the point is on the line?

Comment: QGIS menu: Vector > Geometry Tools > Extract Nodes. Or Processing GRASS v.to.points if you want the points at a given interval along the line.

Answer (score 9):

Use the "Point on surface" tool from the processing toolbox. Despite the name it works also for lines.

[image]

Comment: sorry for the late response. I tried that function and it worked pretty good!

Thanks for the support! :)